# MySQL LDAP authentication

Tags: mysql, security, authentication, authorization

Is LDAP authentication and authorization in MySQL possible? What are the requirements (MySQL version, third-party software etc.)? How it's organized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

use OpenDS with MySQL cluster to implement LDAP

I think [this](http://www.mysqlconf.com/mysql2009/public/schedule/detail/8920) will help a bit...

Answer (score 3):

You can use mysql proxy for this , as it can execute shell commands , intercept and rewrite authentication . [This](http://jan.kneschke.de/2009/6/25/mysql-proxy-roles/) should get you started .

Answer (score -2):

You can use the auth_ldap plugin provided by Infoscope Hellas L.P. under GPL.

It can be downloaded from sourceforge at:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlauthldap/

Homepage:
http://infoscope.gr/mysqlauthldap

The plugin is still a Beta and works only for UNIX installations.